# how to connect irobot by using bluetooth in ROS

Tags: ros, bluetooth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a VM ubuntu on my windows system laptop and i have already installed the ROS in the Ubuntu,i want to connect the IROBOT by using the bluetooth but i dont know what i should do with the ubuntu and ROS.

All the help will be appreciate.

Thanks,
wendy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55236/how-to-connect-irobot-by-using-bluetooth-in-ros/) by [wendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4208/wendy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your VM need an usb-bluetooth dongel, may be it can use the one build in with in the laptop.

then you need the something like the [RooTooth](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/684) as **130s** said

then you pair the Device [HowTo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux)

and then you can use it in the same way as it would be connected with a cord to you PC.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure what you want to ask especially with regard to `ROS`, but if your `roomba` isn't equipped with bluetooth yet, 1st thing to do is to get one. Eg. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/684 Follow whatever instructions that comes with.

Beyond just bluetooth, [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/12152/how-to-get-started-with-irobot-roomba/) gives a lot of hint to use `roomba` with `ROS`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1